# Pass Javascript element as variable

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some testing for an AngularJS app, I don't think the test framework is necessarily important here, but I'm trying to pass an optional variable. This variable will specify if I'm trying to grab a child element of the ID that is passed to the function

```
commonFunctions.elementDoesNotHaveAttribute('register-0', 'disabled', 'children[0].children[0]');
```

the `children[0].children[0]` isn't really a string, if I remove the quotes the function call fails because it can't find a child object of `.children[0]`

Here is the function

```
function elementDoesNotHaveAttribute(id, attribute, child) {
    var hasElement = false;

    hasElement = casper.evaluate(function (id, attribute, child) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (child) {
            element = element.child;
        }        
        return element.hasAttribute(attribute);
    }, id, attribute, child);

    if (hasElement) {
        casper.test.fail('element has' + attribute + ' but shouldn\'t');
    } else {
        casper.test.pass('element didn\'t have ' + attribute + ' and shouldn\'t');
    }
}
```

How can I change either side of these equations to end up evaluating `element.children[0].children[0]` within my function

Comment: that worked, I haven't used eval() much in the past

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it is taking an ID, attribute, and optionally a child element. It is checking to see if that selector as the attribute that is passed or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the "eval hack" I posted in a comment will work, it's a bad idea. Instead, consider passing some kind of "transformation" function.

```
if( child) {
    element = child(element);
}
```

When calling for, say, `children[0].children[0]`, you can do this:

```
commonFunctions.elementDoesNotHaveAttribute(
    'register-0',
    'disabled',
    function(e) {return e.children[0].children[0];}
);
```

The function will take the element and return something else related to it. Adjust the function as needed.

Comment: Good solution, and well done understanding the question, too. :-)

Comment: Works great, thanks for the tip. I like the solution

Comment: Niet, I suggest cleaning up the comments on the question. (*This* comment will self-destruct in five...four...three...)